# Limit on the number of logs that ASL(Apple System Logger) can support

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, logging

Can anyone please tell me if there is a limit to the number of logs that ASL can contain at any given time. The reason i ask is, i have an app that makes use of the ASL to store logs about the program.

But, when i close the app and try populating the ASL with a different set of logs then the previous set of logs gets overwritten, with only a few logs from the previous run getting retained.

Comment: how are you storing the logs? local text file? database?

Comment: I am querying the ASL to get the logs. As the asl stores the logs. Therefore, I want to know the no of logs it can contain.